# Error: Unable to find entry in pubspec.yaml:C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_widget_from_html-0.8.0\test\images\

Tags: flutter, pubspec

After updating some dependency in my pubspec.yaml I started receiving this error "Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_widget_from_html-0.8.0\test\images". So I don't really know whtat is wrong. Here is my pubspec.yaml

```js
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  badges: ^2.0.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.6
  dots_indicator: ^2.0.0
  easy_localization: ^3.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.6
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.6
  flutter_web_browser: ^0.16.0
  flutter_html: ^2.1.0
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.8.0
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
  html: ^0.15.0
  html_unescape: ^2.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.1+3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  line_icons: ^2.0.1
  lottie: ^1.1.0
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  skeleton_text: ^3.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  flutter_math_fork: ^0.4.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.0.0
  youtube_plyr_iframe: ^2.0.7
  rounded_loading_button: ^2.0.5
  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.0
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.0.1
  the_apple_sign_in: ^1.1.1
  video_player: ^2.1.10
  flick_video_player: ^0.4.0-dev
  flutter_icons:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/adarsh-technocrat/flutter-icons
  md2_tab_indicator:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/westdabestdb/md2_tab_indicator

  google_mobile_ads: ^1.0.1
  facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.0"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"


flutter:


  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/animation_files/
    - assets/translations/

  fonts:

    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          weight: 800

    - family: Open Sans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
          weight: 500

    - family: Manrope
      fonts:
       
        - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-Medium.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 900
```

And here is my flutter doctor -v

```js
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.53], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (7 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • itel P651W (mobile) • 062983715I011447 • android-arm    • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Chrome (web)        • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 97.0.4692.99
    • Edge (web)          • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 97.0.1072.62

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cache directory? Sometimes files get corrupted.

Comment: Yes I have. I did invalid cache and restart, flutter clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to upgrade to `v0.8.1+1`

Reference: https://github.com/daohoangson/flutter_widget_from_html/issues/618#issuecomment-950555416